# ibm bluemix auto-scaling behavior

Tags: cloud, scaling, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am new in developing cloud applications and especially new into bluemix.

I want to build an application which regularly executes long-running processes in background.

I have allready read about the [Auto-Scaling Service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Auto-Scaling/index.html#autoscaling) in Bluemix, but I don't get into detail about the scale in behavior.

So what does bluemix do, if the platform initiates the shutdown (e.g. forced by policy) of an instance which is executing a long-running process.

Will the shutdown be forced, or will the long-running process prevent the shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the platform will shut down this instance, because platform does not know whether it's a long-running process or just a instance to cope with temporarily workload. Auto-scaling service is designed for scaling in/out state-less process to handle dynamic workload, so a long-running process might not appropriate for this kind of service.